# Length of a line segment

Tags: probability-distributions

A line segment of length 1 is cut into two pieces at a completely random point. What is the probability that the longer piece is at least three times the length of the shorter piece?

**Attempt**

Let *X* be the length of the shorter piece and *Y* be the length of the longer piece.

*X*: *f(x)* = 2, 0 < *x* < 0.5  or *f(x)* = 0 otherwise

*Y*: *g(y)* = 2, 0.5 < *y* < 1 or *g(y)* = 0 otherwise

I think the question is asking for P[*Y*>= 3 *X*] but I am getting a negative probability.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238542/265466.

Answer (score 1):

If the line was cut at 0.25, then the shorter piece would be 0.25 and the longer piece 0.75, 3 times longer. If the line is cut at a point less than 0.25, the longer piece will be more than 3 times the length of the shorter piece. So I think the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Edit: As rightly pointed out by Badam Baplan, this answer doubles to $\frac{1}{2}$ with symmetry since we can cut the line at a point between 0 and 0.25 or between 0.75 and 1.

Comment: times $2$ for symmetry

Comment: @BadamBaplan Absolutely correct, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The longer piece is at least three times the shorter one when the length of the left piece is in

$$\left[0,\frac14\right]\cup\left[\frac34,1\right].$$

This set has measure $$\frac12.$$

---

This is justified by
$$\frac l{1-l}\le\frac13\lor3\le\frac l{1-l}$$

or

$$3l\le1-l\lor3-3l\le l$$

or

$$4l\le1\lor3\le 4l.$$

Answer (score 0):

$Y=1-X$ so $P(Y \geq 3X)=P(X \leq \frac 1 4)=2\int_0^{1/4}dx=\frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Line segment $AB$ , length $l$, is divided into $4$ equal parts.

From.left to right: $a,b,c,d$, and  $a=b=c=d$.

Probability of cutting randomly within $a,b,c$ or $d$ : $(1/4)$.

Out of these  equally probable choices only $2$ qualify, $a$, and $d$.

$P(a \lor d)= 1/4+1/4=1/2$

Answer (score -1):

You just need to have only one probability function .

considering

```
  y = 3x
  y+x = 1
  3x+x = 1
   x  = 1/4
```

since the probability of one piece having length less than 1/4 answer is 1/4

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).